# Upgrade Gitlab-runner package in amazon Linux 2 and Ubuntu 22.04 through Ansible

Tags: ansible, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Currently our Gitlab runner package is installed in amazon Linux 2 and Ubuntu 22.04 servers (done manually), now regularly we need to update these packages to latest versions.
Instead of manually performing these, we would like to perform these through Ansible, so we can run the playbook which can execute in multiple servers at the same.
Can someone help on this scenario?

We will be running ansible playbook via GitLab CI/CD